# How to find the files in TAGS file in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have generated the TAGS file using ctags for the *.h and *.cpp file in a directory. 
How to find the files in TAGS file.

Assuming i have generated the TAGS file for the files one.h two.h three.h. What is the command to find the file one.h, two.h, three.h not the tags in those files.

Comment: "How to find the files in TAGS file." is awfully vague. If my answer doesn't suffice, perhaps you could clarify the question.

Comment: Maybe its just a typo from you, but for emacs you normally have to use `etags` not `ctags`

Comment: You mean you want an Emacs function to visit the files for which you have information in your TAGS file?  I don't think there is a built-in function for that, but it should be easy enough to do.

Comment: I wish any of these solutions explained how to configure/use them. They probably work if you're wise enough to add them. Like the most recent answer by Bob (Nov 2019), I remember when M-. just worked. Now it doesn't and I is frustrated. :P

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you simply want to know how to use the TAGS file...

Load the TAGS file with:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `visit-tags-table` <kbd>RET</kbd> *TAGS file or parent directory* <kbd>RET</kbd>

Then you can use it with:

- <kbd>M-.</kbd> (i.e. `find-tag`)
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `tags-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> *pattern* <kbd>RET</kbd>
  (with <kbd>M-,</kbd> to move to each successive match)
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `tags-apropos` <kbd>RET</kbd> *pattern* <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `tags-query-replace` <kbd>RET</kbd> *pattern* <kbd>RET</kbd> *replacement* <kbd>RET</kbd>

Those are the defaults. Naturally there are enhancements available:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags

Personally I use `etags-select` (which you can obtain via ELPA), and I have <kbd>M-.</kbd> bound to `etags-select-find-tag`.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this a couple of years ago, I haven't gotten around to releasing it yet, though... Enjoy!

The function `tags-extra-find-file` will let you visit a file in the current tags table, complete with file-name completion. This is perfect if you have many source files spread out over a large number of directories. (Honestly, I use this at least one hundred times every day...)

```
(defun tags-extra-get-all-tags-files ()
  "Return all, fully qualified, file names."
  (save-excursion
    (let ((first-time t))
      (while (visit-tags-table-buffer (not first-time))
        (setq first-time nil)
        (setq res
              (append res (mapcar 'expand-file-name (tags-table-files)))))))
  res))


(defun tags-extra-find-file (name)
  "Edit file named NAME that is part of the current tags table.
The file name should not include parts of the path."
  (interactive
   (list
    (completing-read "Name of file: "
                     ;; Make an a-list of all files without path.
                     (mapcar
                      (lambda (file)
                        (cons (file-name-nondirectory file) nil))
                      (tags-extra-get-all-tags-files)))))
  (let ((files (tags-extra-get-all-tags-files))
        (done nil)
        (name-re (concat "^" (regexp-quote name) "$")))
    (while (and (not done)
                files)
      (let ((case-fold-search t))
        (if (string-match name-re (file-name-nondirectory (car files)))
            (setq done t)
          (setq files (cdr files)))))
    (if files
        (find-file (car files))
      (error "File not found in the tags table."))))
```

Comment: there is an error in the tags-extra-get-all-tags-files function. I corrected in my answer where I use it with ido. Thanks for your answer solving my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This correction works in emacs 26.3. With an old etags, M-. would accept a file name, such as Setup.cpp, and visit the file wherever etags found it. Very handy with lots of files in many directories. No need to remember what directory the file was in to visit it. I'm surprised that's not an out-of-the-box feature!

```
 (defun tags-extra-get-all-tags-files ()
  "Return all, fully qualified, file names."
  (setq res nil)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((first-time t))
      (while (visit-tags-table-buffer (not first-time))
        (setq first-time nil)
        (setq res
              (append res (mapcar 'expand-file-name (tags-table-files)))))))
  res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?  It might not be entirely robust.

```
(defun visit-tags-table-and-files (file)                                        
  "Run `visit-tags-table FILE', then visit all the referenced files."           
  (interactive "fTags file: ")                                                  
  (visit-tags-table file)                                                       
  (save-excursion                                                               
    (set-buffer (get-file-buffer tags-file-name))                               
    (mapc #'find-file (tags-table-files)) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Lindydancer's answer and [emacswiki ido](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#toc12). The emacswiki version only support one tag file. Combining them which allows me jumping to any file in all TAG files. Petty close to the sublime text's goto anything.

Here is the code.

```
;;; using ido find file in tag files
(defun tags-extra-get-all-tags-files ()
  "Return all, fully qualified, file names."
  (save-excursion
    (let ((first-time t)
          (res nil))
      (while (visit-tags-table-buffer (not first-time))
        (setq first-time nil)
        (setq res
              (append res (mapcar 'expand-file-name (tags-table-files)))))
      res)))

(defun ido-find-file-in-tag-files ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file
   (expand-file-name
    (ido-completing-read
     "Files: " (tags-extra-get-all-tags-files) nil t))))
```